# Generalised formula for fitting a cubic between two points with specified slopes at each point

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, cubics

As the question says, I'd like to fit a cubic between two points, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.  The reason I need a cubic is that I want to specify the first differential at each point.  I can see instances when there would be an infinite number of solutions - for example, if $y_1 = y_2$, $x_2 > x_1$, and the slope at $(x_1,y_1)$ has the opposite sign to that at $(x_2,y_2)$, then a quadratic could do the job; however, if - for example - $x_2 > x_1$, $y_2 > y_1$, the slope at $(x_1,y_1)$ is positive and the slope at $(x_2,y_2)$ is negative, then I think only a cubic can do the job. More generally, I think that if a straight line drawn through $(x_1,y_1)$ with the specified slope would go through $(x_2,y_2)$ but the corresponding line drawn through $(x_2,y_2)$ would not go through $(x_1,y_1)$, then it would need to be a cubic.

It is possible (I believe) to take some simultaneous equations and solve your way though them to find the parameters for the cubic...but I wanted to see if anyone else has already done this and can share the answer! Thoughts?

Comment: Charles Hermite made it long ago. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline

Comment: tomi - thanks for tidying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your polynomial is some $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, $p'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$, with four unknown parameters $a,b,c,d$.

Two points give two equations $p(x_i)=y_i$, two slopes two more: $p'(x_i) = m_i$.

In matrix form:
$$
A=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\
x_2^3 & x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 \\
3x_2^2 & 2x_2 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad
x=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad
b=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
m_1 \\
m_2
\end{matrix}
\right)
\\
Ax=b \\
x = A^{-1} b
$$
Then for $x_1 \ne x_2$:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
x_2^3 & x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 & y_2 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
3x_2^2 & 2x_2 & 1 & 0 & m_2
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
3(x_2^2 - x_1^2) & 2(x_2 - x_1) & 0 & 0 & m_2 - m_1 \\
x_2^3 & x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 & y_2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
3(x_2^2 - x_1^2) & 2(x_2 - x_1) & 0 & 0 & m_2 - m_1 \\
x_2^3 - x_1^3 & x_2^2 - x_1^2 & x_2 - x_1 & 0 & y_2 - y_1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
3(x_2^2 - x_1^2) & 2(x_2 - x_1) & 0 & 0 & m_2 - m_1 \\
x_1^2 + x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 & x_1 + x_2 & 1 & 0 & \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
3(x_2^2 - x_1^2) & 2(x_2 - x_1) & 0 & 0 & m_2 - m_1 \\
-2 x_1^2 + x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 & x_2 - x_1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} - m_1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
3(x_2^2 - x_1^2) & 2(x_2 - x_1) & 0 & 0 & m_2 - m_1 \\
-4 x_1^2 + 2 x_1 x_2 + 2 x_2^2 & 2(x_2 - x_1) & 0 & 0 & 2\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} - 2m_1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
x_1^2 - 2 x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m_1 + m_2 - 2\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}\\
-4 x_1^2 + 2 x_1 x_2 + 2 x_2^2 & 2(x_2 - x_1) & 0 & 0 & 2\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} - 2m_1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
3 (x_2^2-x_1^2) & 2(x_2 - x_1) & 0 & 0 &  m_2 - m_1 \\
x_1^2 - 2 x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m_1 + m_2 - 2\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}\\
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
\frac{3}{2} (x_1+x_2) & 1 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{m_2 - m_1}{2(x_2-x_1)} \\
(x_1 - x_2)^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m_1 + m_2 - 2\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}\\
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & y_1 \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1 & 0 & m_1 \\
\frac{3}{2} (x_1+x_2) & 1 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{m_2 - m_1}{2(x_2-x_1)} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{m_1 + m_2 - 2\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}}{(x_1 - x_2)^2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
This gives:
\begin{align}
a &= \frac{m_1 + m_2 - 2\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}}{(x_1 - x_2)^2} \\
b &= \frac{m_2 - m_1}{2(x_2-x_1)} - \frac{3}{2} (x_1+x_2) a \quad (*) \\
c &= m_1 - 3x_1^2 a - 2x_1 b \\
d &= y_1 - x_1^3 a - x_1^2 b - x_1  c
\end{align}

The last two equations seem obvious in hind sight.

**Test:**

```
octave:1> x1 = 2
x1 =  2
octave:2> x2 = 5
x2 =  5
octave:3> m1 = 3
m1 =  3
octave:4> m2 = -1
m2 = -1
octave:6> A = [x1**3, x1**2, x1, 1; x2**3, x2**2, x2**1, 1;
3*x1**2,2*x1,1,0; 3*x2**2,2*x2,1,0]
A =
     8     4     2     1
   125    25     5     1
    12     4     1     0
    75    10     1     0

octave:17> y1=-2
y1 = -2
octave:18> y2=5
y2 =  5
octave:19> b = [y1;y2;m1;m2]
b =
  -2
   5
   3
  -1

octave:20> x = inv(A)*b
x =
  -0.29630
   2.44444
  -3.22222
  -2.96296
```

Now we compare this with equation $(*)$

```
octave:22> a = (m1+m2-2*(y2-y1)/(x2-x1))/(x1-x2)**2
a = -0.29630
octave:23> b = (m2-m1)/(2*(x2-x1))-(3/2)*(x1+x2)*a
b =  2.4444
octave:24> c = m1-3*(x1**2)*a -2*x1*b
c = -3.2222
octave:25> d = y1-(x1**3)*a -(x1**2)*b-x1*c
d = -2.9630
```

Comment: Thanks - I initially wanted to find results for a in terms of the x's, y's and m's, as this is something I'll be using to calculate paths on a web page (canvas) - but I've found a js library that does matrix algebra, so I'll probably go with this approach.

Comment: I tansformed it into a diagonal matrix, to derive some formulas. A test needs to be added to guard abit  against calculation errors. :-)

Comment: That test seems to work.

Comment: Excellent - thanks, I'll be bookmarking this page for future reference!

Answer (score 3):

Look at [interpolating with cubic splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation#Algorithm_to_find_the_interpolating_cubic_spline)

Comment: Thanks - should have looked there first!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a spline segment from $x=0 \ldots h$. If the end points are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and the end slopes $\dot{Y}_1$ and $\dot{Y}_2$ then the curve can be defined as:

$$ \begin{align} y(x) & = \left( 2 \left(\tfrac{x}{h}\right)^3-3 \left(\tfrac{x}{h}\right)^2+1 \right) Y_1 \\
& + \left( \left(\tfrac{x}{h}\right)^2 \left(3 - 2 \tfrac{x}{h} \right) \right) Y_2 \\ & +  x \left( \left(\tfrac{x}{h}\right)^2-2 \left(\tfrac{x}{h}\right)+1 \right) \dot{Y}_1 \\ &+  \tfrac{x^2}{h} \left(\left(\tfrac{x}{h}\right)-1\right) \dot{Y}_2
\end{align} $$

To go between slopes and curvatures $\ddot{Y}_1$ and $\ddot{Y}_2$ solve this system of equations:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \dot{Y}_1 \\ \dot{Y}_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} -\tfrac{1}{h} & \tfrac{1}{h} \\ -\tfrac{1}{h} & \tfrac{1}{h} \end{vmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} -\tfrac{h}{3} & -\frac{h}{6} \\ \tfrac{h}{6} & \tfrac{h}{3} \end{vmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \ddot{Y}_1 \\ \ddot{Y}_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: The reason traditional cubic spline implementation relies on curvature $\ddot{Y}_i$ parameters is that a) it simplifies the curve function to $$y(x) = (1-\frac{x}{h}) Y_1 + \frac{x}{h} Y_2 + \ldots$$ and because it makes it easy to establish natural splines with no curvature at the ends.